# Ruby on rails error in .each statement

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
<% temp1= "secondary" %>
<% @query = "select  credentials_id from credentials where credentials_id LIKE '%" + temp1 + "%'" %>
<% Request.connection.execute(@query) %>

<% if @query.blank? %>
    <p>These are no  secondary users still created </p>
<% else %>
    <% @query.each do |c| %>
        <%= label_tag(:credentials_id,c.credentials_id)%>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

I am trying to execute the code above, that I have written in my "admin.html.erb" file, but I´m getting the following error:

> undefined method 'each' for #

Comment: Can you add some more error backtrace?

Comment: Aside from the correction the Glauco has found for you, you might want   to consider using the Request model, rather than dropping down to the connection level

Answer (score 1):

The `@query` variable is just an `String`. If you want to iterate over every single character on that string, you should use `each_char` method.

I really believe that you're iterating over the wrong variable. I think you want to iterate over the result of your query, not over your query characters! For that you should do something like:

```
<% @query_result = Request.connection.execute(@query) %>
<% @query_result.each do |c| %>
    <%= label_tag(:credentials_id,c.credentials_id)%>
<%end%>
```